# Styling language switcher - flags (polylang + wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, polylang

I have problem with styling the language switcher on site. I've changed the flags and now I would like to have different icons on current lang.

I make this for current:

```
li.lang-item.lang-item-2.lang-item-se.lang-item-first.current-lang a {
    background-image: url(../gfx/flag/lang_se_ac.png);
}
```

but as you can see this background display under the main image.
I try to set z-index, position but ineffectively.

[image: As you can see current icon is under the SE flag]

Comment: Are you sure that inside the anchor tags, the default flags are not images with img tags?

Comment: See the whole code https://s3.postimg.org/rwa4utdyb/code.png

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, the plugin uses img tags and not CSS background-image property.

There is [documentation](https://polylang.pro/doc/can-i-use-my-own-flags-for-the-language-switcher/) available on how to change flags.

It says the following:

> You have to use PNG or JPG files and name them with the WordPress
>   locale. For example, en_US.png.
>
> Upload these files in the /wp-content/polylang/ directory.
>
> Note: You have to create the directory yourself. Don’t use the
>   /polylang/flags/ directory.

Comment: Yes, I understand, read documentation and change flags. In my case I'd like to set additionaly effects to this flags - hover and active (current lang). In this option I need to replace the img's. I thought it could be possible in css.

Comment: If current flag has some sort of "active" class, then it should be possible with CSS.